# how to remove parts of a url with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

My url contains a broken link due to the http:// prefix not being added in places. How would I replace this using mod_rewrite:

```
http://website.com/www.websitelink.com
```

should go here:

```
http://www.websitelink.com
```

Comment: search for htaccess on stackoverflow.  Someone will have already answered this.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to fix the offending links? Or are they beyond your control?

Comment: the links are beyond my control unfortunately...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^www\.websitelink\.com$ http://www.websitelink.com/ [R=301,NC,L]
```

In other words, if your path *is* /www.websitelink.com (`^` is start of string,`$` is end of string; in regular expressions, dots are one-character wildcards and have to be escaped)
(and `[NC]` matching is not case sensitive - /WwW.webSiteLink.COM would match, too),

`[R=301]` redirect with status "301 (Moved Permanently)"
to http://www.websitelink.com/
and `[L]` leave processing (no more rewrite rules are processed).

Note that this will work regardless of the site's domain (would work e.g. for http://website.com/www.websitelink.com and http://www.website.com/www.websitelink.com )

If you want to match all the paths that end with your domain, drop the starting `^`:

```
RewriteRule www\.websitelink\.com$ http://www.websitelink.com/ [R=301,NC,L]
```

and if you want to match even paths without `www.`, make it optional:

```
RewriteRule (www\.)?websitelink\.com$ http://www.websitelink.com/ [R=301,NC,L]
```

As [@Litso](https://stackoverflow.com/users/124238/litso) noted, this won't match the path after the "domain-in-path"; this should match the trailing path:

```
RewriteRule (www\.)?websitelink\.com/(.*)$ http://www.websitelink.com/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

To match any subdomain:

```
RewriteRule ([a-z0-9.-]+\.)?websitelink\.com/(.*)$ http://www.websitelink.com/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

And to match any domain:

```
RewriteRule ([a-z0-9.-]+\.)?([a-z0-9.-]+)\.com/(.*)$ http://www.$1.com/$2 [R=301,NC,L]
```

Comment: If you want to replace all traffic that includes the domain name as a folder and not just the main page, use:
`RewriteRule ^www\.websitelink\.com/(.*)$ http://www.websitelink.com/$1 [R=301,NC,L]`

The (.*) catches evertything behind the domainname.com and $1 inserts that back into the right url

Comment: this doesnt seem to be working for me: some of the URLS dont have the www. prefix i.e.: http://mywebsite.com/myfolder/websitelink.co.uk

Comment: @Litso: Quite correct. Do you want to post that as your own answer, or shall I edit it into mine?

Comment: @InnateDev: If they don't have the prefix, of course they won't match the pattern which contains the prefix. That's a *little bit* different from your question; edited my answer.

Comment: @piskvor just add it to yours ;)

Comment: sorry about that - Im fairly new to htaccess. Now ideally the websitelink part should be some sort of wildcard - do I just replace this with (.*) and then $1 in the redirect to url?

Comment: so this is what I have working: RewriteRule (www\.)?(.*)\.com$ http://www.$1.com/ [R=301,NC,L]